# How to include more data about a test in generated test program documentation?

Tags: origen-sdk

After generating the flow and running the `origen web compile` command, web documentation is generated where each test has a set of data listed, specifically the test name and the name of the pattern.

Is it possible to include all of the test data such as the level set used or other details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you assign to a test suite/instance's `meta` property (a Ruby hash) will appear in the documentation.

```rb
my_test_suite.meta = { vdd: "Max", speed: "200MHz" }
```